# Is it true that $K(G \ast H, 1) = K(G,1)\vee K(H,1) $?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

I know that, unlike the case of the fundamental group (where $\pi_1(X \vee Y) \cong 
\pi_1(X)\ast \pi_1(Y)$ at least for CW complexes, which are the spaces I care about for the purpose of this question), there is no straightforward formula for the higher homotopy groups of a wedge sum of spaces.

However, I was wondering whether in the case that $\pi_k(X) = \pi_k(Y) = 0$ for all $k \geq 2$ one can deduce that also $\pi_k(X\vee Y) = 0$ for all $k \geq 2$. If this is true, how can one show this? I don't necessarily need a full solution, a hint to get started would be enough.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is true (at least, for nice spaces like CW complexes).  As a sketch of a proof, observe that you can construct a universal cover for $X\vee Y$ by gluing together copies of a universal cover of $X$ and a universal cover of $Y$ at preimages of the basepoint. (You can in fact give a combinatorial description of how the copies are glued together which parallels the description of $\pi_1(X)*\pi_1(Y)$ in terms of reduced words.)  Since the universal covers of $X$ and $Y$ are contractible, it follows easily that the universal cover of $X\vee Y$ has trivial homology in dimensions greater than $1$, and so it is contractible.

(There are other ways you could do the last step besides using homology; for instance, you could contract the copies of the universal covers of $X$ and $Y$ to a point one by one which does not change the homotopy type since they are contractible; here you use the combinatorics of how they are attached to ensure that no copy can get glued together with itself when you contract other copies.)

Comment: Great, I hadn't thought of using homology + Hurewicz. Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in your comment about the combinatorics of the attachments used to form the universal cover. Where could I read more about that?

Comment: You can finid a nice illustrated example at https://www.math3ma.com/blog/a-recipe-for-the-universal-cover-of-x-y.  It's also very instructive to just think about the usual tree depiction of the universal cover of $S^1\vee S^1$ as a union of horizontal and vertical segments which are covers of the two circles.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, see the question and comments at [overflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96451/does-the-classifying-space-of-monoids-commute-with-wedge-sum-up-to-weak-equivale).

The answer there explains the map $$BG\vee BH \to B(G*H)$$ is a weak equivalence more generally for topological groups, or even topological monoids.