# Wedge product of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.

Tags: homotopy-theory, eilenberg-maclane-spaces

It is the case that [the wedge product of aspherical spaces is aspherical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186874/is-it-true-that-kg-ast-h-1-kg-1-vee-kh-1), so in particular $K(G, 1) \vee K(H, 1) \simeq K(G*H, 1)$.

I know homotopy groups are notoriously poorly behaved with respect to coproducts/pushouts, but is an analogous result true for at least for Eilenberg-MacLane spaces with higher and arbitrary dimensions? Specifically, if $X\simeq K(G, n) \vee K(H, m)$ for $n, m > 1$, then could anyone verify or provide counter-examples to the following claims:

> 1) If $n = m$ then $X \simeq K(G\oplus H, n)$.
>
> 2) If $n \neq m$ then $\pi_n(X) \cong G$, $\pi_m(X)\cong H$ and $\pi_k(X) = 0$ if $k\neq n, m$.

Note that in order to expect 2) to be true for all $G, H$ we need both $n$ and $m$ to be greater than $1$, because if we choose $G$ to have an element of infinite order, $n=1$,  and $H$ to be finitely generated then $\pi_m(X)$ will nevertheless be infinitely generated (by considering the universal cover) and so can't be $H$.

For 1) I at least know that $\pi_n(X) \cong G \oplus H$ by the Hurewicz theorem, but I don't know how to address the higher homotopy groups of the wedge. For 2) I know that if $n < m$ then $\pi_n(X) \cong G$ and otherwise $\pi_m(X) \cong H$ but again I don't know how to approach the higher homotopy groups. My feeling is that 2) is much less likely to be true than 1).

Comment: In both cases the space you're looking for with those properties is the product $K(G, n) \times K(H, m)$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for the comment, in retrospect that should have been obvious. Do you then see that the wedge of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces is not homotopy-equivalent to the cartesean product by looking at cohomology?

Comment: Yes, at least that they're not homotopy equivalent most of the time.

Comment: You can often work out Qiaochu's comment quite easily. Take $m,n>1$ for simplicity and assume $p,q$ are distinct primes. If the group $G$ is $p$-local, then so is the space $K(G,m)$, which implies that the cohomology groups $H^*K(G,m)$ are $p$-local. Now if $H$ is $q$-local the same argument applies to $H^*K(H,m)$ with $q$ in place of $p$. Finally use the Kunneth formula to calculate $\widetilde H^*(K(G,n)\wedge K(H,m))=0$. This implies that the inclusion of the wedge into the product is a cohomological equivalence, and hence a homotopy equivalence (since $n,m>1$).